# Discord.py delete message on_raw_reaction_add

Tags: discord.py, bots

I have done a little discord bot in python, and it's working ! I have one little issue on it : i want the message send by the bot (line 11) to be delete when someone react :( how can i do it ?

```
@commands.command()
async def casino(self, ctx, arg):
    embed = (Embed(title=f"Viens défier {ctx.message.author.name} qui mets en jeu {arg} po!", description=f"Appuies sur les <:goldcoin:857043361813889044> pour un /rand avec {ctx.message.author.name} :)")
             .add_field(name="<:goldcoin:857043361813889044>Joueur 1", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}", inline = False)
             .add_field(name="<:goldcoin:857043361813889044>Joueur 2", value="<:goldcoin:857043361813889044>", inline = False)
             .set_footer(text=f"Défi de {ctx.author.display_name}"))
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    emojis = ['<:goldcoin:857043361813889044>', '<:deny:849631648135118889>']
    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await ctx.send("<@&857916481747943434> A vos golds !")

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    member = payload.member
    if member.bot:
        return

    channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    try:
        if not message.embeds:
            return
        if 'Viens défier' not in message.embeds[0].title:
            return
    except:
        return

    possible_responses = [str(i) for i in range(1, 101)]
    emoji = payload.emoji
    reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji)
    embed = message.embeds[0]

    if emoji.name == 'deny':
        if member.display_name in embed.footer.text:
            for reac in message.reactions:
                await reac.clear()
            await message.edit(content='Défi annulé', embed=None)
        elif payload.member in get(member.guild.roles, id=849270094952792084).members:
            for reac in message.reactions:
                await reac.clear()
            await message.edit(content='Défi annulé', embed=None)
        else:
            await reaction.remove(member)
        return

    names = [field.name for field in embed.fields]
    values = [field.value for field in embed.fields]
    test = values[0]

    index = ['', 'goldcoin'].index(emoji.name)

    result1 = random.choice(possible_responses)
    result2 = random.choice(possible_responses)

    bravo1 = f"Bravo {test} ! Tu as gagné avec un {result1} !"
    bravo2 = f"Bravo {payload.member.mention} ! Tu as gagné avec un {result2} !"

    if values.count(member.mention) >= 1:
        await channel.send("Tu as déjà joué, attends un peu", delete_after=5)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member); return
    elif '@' in values[1]:
        await channel.send("Quelqu'un a déjà joué, retente ta chance !", delete_after=5)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member); return

    embed.set_field_at(index, name=f"<:goldcoin:857043361813889044>Tu as fait : {result2} !", value=f"{payload.member.mention}", inline=False)
    embed.set_field_at(0, name=f"<:goldcoin:857043361813889044>Tu as fait : {result1} !", value=f"{test}", inline=False)
    await message.edit(embed=embed)
    if result1 > result2:
        await channel.send(bravo1)
    elif result1 < result2:
        await channel.send(bravo2)
    elif result1 == result2:
        await channel.send("EGALITEEEEEE")

    if (message != None) and (message.content == "<@&857916481747943434> A vos golds !"):
        await message.delete() 


@casino.error
async def casino_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Merci d'utiliser le bot avec ?casino XX. Exemple: ?casino 100", delete_after=25)
        await ctx.message.delete(delay=25)
```

def setup(bot):
bot.add_cog(Casino(bot))

I tried with "if message.content()" but it's not doing anything :(
thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where is the problem in the code you shared? What isn't working?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, i just don't know how to delete the line 11 after someone react

Comment: [send()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) has return type `Message`, which has an `id` property. So take the `id` from the return object and save it in a database or other persistent cache. Then you can use [raw events](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md) to run your deletion code whenever you receive a reaction event where the reaction's message id matches your saved one.

Comment: Thanks Noah :) I'm learning and atm, i just don't know how to save the id in a persistent cache (i don't even talk about database, you lost me there xD )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically already said in your title what you need. Whats missing is just the code

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload): 
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    async for msg in channel.history(after = message, limit = 20):
        if (msg != None) and (msg.content == "<@&857916481747943434> A vos golds !"):
        await msg.delete()
```

---

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    member = payload.member

    channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    async for msg in channel.history(after = message, limit = 20):
        if (msg != None) and (msg.content == "<@&857916481747943434> A vos golds !"):
        await msg.delete()

    if member.bot:
        return

    try:
        if not message.embeds:
            return
        if 'Viens défier' not in message.embeds[0].title:
            return
    except:
        return
    # code continues
```

Comment: Thanks :) But it isn't working T__T

I edit the first post, with the all code, it may be easier to find :/

Comment: `if not message.embeds: return` you're returning before the `.delete()` gets called. Move the `.delete()` above the return. I'll edit my answer with the extra info you provided

Comment: Same thing with `if member.bot: return`.

Comment: i did exactly what you did but it isn't working :/
edit: it did nothing more btw

Comment: i place it before any return, but it isn't deleting that @casino...
https://i.postimg.cc/jdsmfQkq/casino.jpg

Comment: Well you didn't react to the message. You said you want to delete the message when someone reacts to it. And if you do, it should get deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english :/ when someone react with the gold emoji on the embed, i want delete the "<@&857916481747943434> A vos golds !" message :S

Comment: Then getting the message without saving its id gets a bit more complicated. I'll  think of something and update my answer shortly

Comment: I'm ok to save its id.. Just don't know how to do :S I tried to use "global variable" but it isn't working :(

Comment: Thank you !!!! It works ! I had to put it after the "await message.edit(embed=embed)" because where you placed it, the message appears and disappears instantanly :) But where i placed it, it works perfectly :) Thanks you again !